# React complains about unique keys inside div having two static elements

Tags: reactjs, key

I understand that elements should have unique key properties when created inside a loop.

But what I don't understand is why React is complaining about this situation where there is no loop and there is only 2 elements always, and especially why it complains about the key only related to the second element and apparently does not need unique key for the first popOverBlockContent:

```
return (
    <div>
          <PopOverBlockContent>
             ...contents removed
          </PopOverBlockContent>
    
          {results && (
            <PopOverBlockContent key={2}>
                 ...contents removed
                {results.map((result) => (
                   <div key={result.id}>
                           
                     <PopoverDataRows
                        key={result.id}
                        ...etc...
                        />
                   </div>
            </PopOverBlockContent>
          )}
    </div>
)
```

I see this pattern in other parts of my code as well - as soon as I add a conditional expression, react starts requiring me to add key to that element inside conditional part - like it would mix conditionality to loops. But for test purposes I added the same conditional expression on top of the first element, but it did not start complaining about the key.

I tried to add key={2} for the 2nd element and also tried with adding key={1} to first element, but none of these combinations solved the issue. There will never be any real keys available for these two ui-components I'm listing inside div so I dont see why something like values 1 and 2 would not work here.

I have a loop inside the 2nd element, and because its a loop I'm of course adding a key there, and those keys are perfectly unique as well works perfectly and makes perfect sense, so I dont see why that would cause a problem either for the higher level.

This is the error i get to console:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of ``

```
  163 |       )}
  164 |       {results && (
> 165 |         <PopOverBlockContent key={2}>
      |         ^
```

Comment: What does PopOverBlockContent look like?  Are there any iterations in there?  Also, (assuming this is a custom component you wrote) is it accounting for the `key` attribute if passed in?

Comment: It is only a styledComponent, created from a Div

Comment: but indeed I append a second element PopoverDataRows inside it, in a loop. currently giving same key for the div surrounding popoverdatarows and popoverdatarows, but as those are not siblings i guess its ok.

Comment: Luckily seems like I'm proceeding after all. There seemed to be a problem in my test data, I was missing the ids there that i was using to identifiy contents inside  the 2nd block inside {results.map((result) => ( . so after all it seems that the problems deeper in the component chaing progagated higher level - I was expecting that the problems would have been pinpointed exactly where is the root cause of the problems because this is so much harder to track - anyway i good lesson to know. Now I have a next similar problem to track down.

Comment: And that's it, the 2nd problem got fixed in similar fashion. I had to look down deeper into the nested components to find the unique key problem - it was just so misleading from my console errors to pinpoint the problem at higher level than where there was not even a loop at those pinpointed code rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a detailed explanation, but I would guess that the problem is related to multiple elements grouped in a condition code block without having a parent element inside this block. Try wrapping the elements with `<></>`:

```js
 <div>
          <PopOverBlockContent>
             ...contents removed
          </PopOverBlockContent>
    
          {results && (
            <>
              <PopOverBlockContent key={2}>
               ...contents removed
                {results.map((result) => (
                     <div key={result.id}>
                       ...contents removed
                     </div>
              </PopOverBlockContent>
            </>
          )}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my indentation a bit to make it more clearer: PopOverBlockContent is the only element at that level, so there should not be need to wrap it around <>

Comment: My fault, I was reading it on mobile, so got the wrong impression that the closing tag is a second element